# Asus laptop wake from Hibernate fails while on battery

Tags: windows-10, battery, hibernate, asus-laptop

My Asus X556U laptop running Windows 10 refuses to wake from hibernate (using a wake timer) while on battery.  It has no problem waking if the laptop is plugged in.

I've tried running the power troubleshooter.  It did not find any problems.  I've tried writing my own scheduled task to wake the machine.  I get the same results.

I've checked the event log to verify that the wake timer does wake the machine if its plugged in.  I see no wake event if on battery.   I have “allow wake timers” enabled.  I've also reset the file hyberfil.sys.

I'm not sure if this is a Bios issue, or, something else.  I could use some help investigating this.

Comment: Have you tried resetting your power scheme back to default? Open a command prompt (run, CMD.EXE) type __powercfg –restoredefaultschemes__ and the hit Enter.

Comment: @vssher - Yes, that was one of the first things I tried.